# When File Selected Change Label Contents instead the default text in the label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So, I'm attempting to make my file upload input look a little bit better than the default buttons. All is going well, however, I can't seem to find a jQuery script which can do what I want it to do.

What I want to happen is, when a file isn't selected, I would like the label to display "Choisir le recto", but when a file is selected, I would like it to display the files name, i.e: "example.png" instead of "Choisir le recto".

```js
$('input[type=file]').change(function() {
  var filename = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
  var idname = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log($(this));
  console.log(filename);
  console.log(idname);
  $('span.' + idname).next().find('span').html(filename);
});
```

```css
.btnsend {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.labelbtn {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0057a0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}

.labelbtn:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #0072a0;
}

.sendall {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="recto" id="recto" class="btnsend" />
  <label for="recto" class="labelbtn"><span> Choisir le Recto</span></label>
  <input type="file" name="verso" id="verso" class="btnsend" />
  <label for="verso" class="labelbtn"><span>Choisir le Verso</span></label>
  <input type="file" name="selfie" id="selfie" class="btnsend" />
  <label for="selfie" class="labelbtn"><span>Choisir le Selfie</span></label> <br>


  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="sendall">
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the way you're attempting to find the relevant `span` in the DOM. You can just use the `this` keyword to refer to the `input` which raised the `change` event, then `next()` and `find()` from there:

```js
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
  var filename = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
  $(this).next().find('span').html(filename);
});
```

```css
.btnsend {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.labelbtn {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0057a0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}

.labelbtn:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #0072a0;
}

.sendall {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="recto" id="recto" class="btnsend" />
  <label for="recto" class="labelbtn"><span>Choisir le Recto</span></label>
  
  <input type="file" name="verso" id="verso" class="btnsend" />
  <label for="verso" class="labelbtn"><span>Choisir le Verso</span></label>
  
  <input type="file" name="selfie" id="selfie" class="btnsend" />
  <label for="selfie" class="labelbtn"><span>Choisir le Selfie</span></label> <br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="sendall" /> 
</form>
```